# Background image not visible while testing on device

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an app that has a background image set which is perfectly visible while testing on the simulator but it is not visible when i test on my device. I am testing the app on Iphone 3GS iOS 4.1.

Comment: how you added that background image by coding or in xib

Comment: Please check the image name ,Eventhough you give a.png in Simulator instead of A.png it displays in Simulator but not in Device .Clean your app also .

Comment: May be this is the case sensitive issue. Image set in Xib or in code?

Comment: check your image extension.and Recreate that image .

Comment: check if the image which is not coming on simulator has been added to your project bundle or not else on simulator it will take the local path and will show it but on device it won't .

Comment: Delete the app from the simulator, run again check if image is still there if not check the image membership target. Otherwise insure you spelt it right as a device is case sensitive and simulator is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be multiple issues,
1. The image name you provided is not proper, since simulator is not case sensitive whereas device is, so you need to check the name of the image.
2. Reference of the image in project. So try by deleting reference from project and then again do "Add files to".
3. There may be multiple images with same name. So search in project for the image name and verify that is there multiple images.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you run app in simulator it takes name as **case insensitive** but in device it checks **case sensitivity**. So check the image name you are using. Is it correct.

Hope it helps you.